# How to name one who expects something?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word in English that denotes a person who expects something to happen?

- writer writes
- reader reads
- ? expects

Comment: What are you trying to say?  Is there a context for this, or are you asking because you are curious?  The words suggested in the answers, while legitimate words, are not common.

Comment: I am trying to find a word for an interface in a software system that has a single method "Expect"

Comment: 'expect' may not be the right verb for that function as its unclear what it's doing. You might ask at SO to see what might be more standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Expecter**

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expecter):

> one that expects

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/expecter):

> a person who expects

Answer (score 1):

An **anticipator** expects something to happen. Lexico has this definition of the [verb](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/anticipate).

> **anticipate**
>   VERB
>
> **1** Regard as probable; expect or predict.

The [noun](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/anticipator) form gives this example

> *He is a great anticipator who makes up for a lack of speed with toughness and size*

although it is more suitable for the *predict* definition.